# Safe to use other peripherals after motherboard has gotten fried?

Tags: usb, hardware-failure, peripherals

This might be a very stupid question, but I recently managed to fry my motherboard through one of my USB-A ports. The other USB devices plugged into the motherboard SEEM fine, but are they actually safe to use once I get a replacement motherboard? Or could they pose some sort of risk?

Comment: What did you do to cause the damage?

Comment: I was negligent and failed to pay attention and accidentally put a USB-C dongle into a USB-A port. Not my proudest moment, but that's what happened.

Comment: If they are bus powered devices and the connectors are not damaged I wouldn't worry.

Comment: For that matter, it might just be the USB-A port and controller that have died. If there are other working ports and **if the PC boots**, no big deal -- use a hub for more ports.

Comment: The PC does in fact not boot, so I still have to figure out exactly how extensive the damaged is. But thank you for the answers, hopefully there won't be any further issues with anything once I figure out what needs to be replaced.